# Host reachability using ping command in C program

Tags: c, ip, ip-address, ping

I am quite new to C environment. I want to write a program in which i need to add a functionality where I input a an IP address and that function should directly tell me whether this IP address is reachable or not. Any pointers? 
-Thanks

Comment: The beauty of Open Source. [ping source code](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/networking/ping.c).

Comment: Btw, with Firewalls doing all kind of crazy filtering nowadays, no method is really reliable except trying to make exactly the connection you need and see whether it succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use the same methods as the actual `ping` command, or something simpler? If you want something simpler, just try to do a TCP connection to the system using a random port number, you will get different errors if the system is not reachable or if it is reachable but no one is listening on that port (or you get a connection, which you then promptly close).

If using TCP connections, you might get a long (many seconds) timeout though, as TCP tries and retries to connect. Also, if the system is reachable such a probe might be seen as an intrusion attempt, while a ping (ICMP echo request) is not.

Another caveat is that both TCP connection attempts and ICMP echo request might be stopped anywhere from your system to the remote system by a firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured out the issue, it was with my linux flavor. Generally it should check for timeout event after certain time but in my machine I need to explicitly mention it.

Well, I figured what was the issue. Apparently for few flavors of linux you need to explicitly mention -w filer. so my solution is :

```
Well, I figured what was the issue. Apparently for few flavors of linux you need to explicitly mention -w filer. so my solution is :

if ( system("ping -c1 128.205.159.60 -w 2 ") == 0)
    {
        printf ("\n Exists");
    }
    else
    {   printf ("\n Not reachable ");
    }
```

Thanks everyone for your input. :)

Comment: This is the worst possible "solution". You don't spawn an external tool without a **strong** need -- it creates all kinds of problems (depending on the existence of the tool, and, in your case, proper `$PATH` setting) *and* wastes resources for forking etc.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Could you please provide me reason behind it. I am quite new in this domain so I can learn from it.

Comment: Sorry, just decided to add some reasoning -- at a minimum, you'd have to check the return value of `system()` for `-1`to catch cases where trying to execute ping failed. Better just do the ICMP echo request in your code.

Comment: Ohh ok. I will try to work on it. Thanks for sharing this info. I will look into ICMP echo request and try to work on return code form it.